# Refurbishing everyday bikes

Tags: derailleur, replacement

I'm looking to get 3 family bikes functioning as well as possible. I've replaced all the cables, but now want to get the gears as close to new as is sensible.
All bikes old >10 years I would guess:Trek 4300, Kona Lana'i & Ridgeback mx24. 
Initial Q is, apart from the chain & cassette, which gear  components degrade the most? Rear mech, front mech, shifters & chainring.
Trying to do a cost-benefit analysis.
Ta

Comment: My rule of thumb is that a chain lasts 2000 miles, and a rear cluster lasts 5000 (though it will wear out faster if the chain is worn).  Chainrings are good for 10-15K.  And of course, cables corrode and tires wear out or rot and crack.  First off get yourself an inexpensive chain wear gauge.

Comment: Just done some quick & dirty calcs on a 10 yo bike that would be 10 miles/wk every week, every year. Hasn't happened on any of those bikes, esp as they've been variously laid up sor misc years here & there.

Comment: Yeah, I spend two afternoons a week rehabbing donated bikes for Christmas Anonymous and other charities.  It is very, very rare to find a bike with a worn-out chain or cog (though there have been more than a few chains rusted solid).  The biggest single problem is busted shifters, then corroded cables.  And tires -- new tires are expensive, and probably a third of the bikes coming in have rotted tires.

Comment: Thanks, Just done some quick & dirty calcs: on a 10 yo bike 2k would be 5 miles/wk every week, every year. That probablyhasn't happened on any of those bikes, esp as they've been laid up for misc years here & there.  So notionally, the chains & cassettes should be OK, let alone the mechs. Therefore is poor gear shifting purely down to cables & adjustments?  That would be good news as I was planning on replacing any/all worn parts & taking them to get the gears adjusted by a pro.  May not be as simple as that & may need to get them looked over with an experienced eye.

Comment: Thanks - long edit disallowed! Very useful insight - shifters probably the bits to replace esp as some broken plastic housings.  Tyres are not too bad as bikes have been pressed into service sporadically & re-shod.  Ours are just the kind of bikes a charity would get! OK for general use & enough to get me back out to see if I want to invest further.

Comment: Do you know if I can straight swap from Gripshift to something like EZ fires?

Comment: @DanielRHicks would know better than me but I've had partial success at getting old gummy grease out of shifters with lots of wd40 and diluting what's left with oil. Not perfect but seems to deal with the reluctant ratchets.

Comment: Both of the EZ fires have seen better days through missing covers & opaque indicator windows etc, so I wouldn't begrudge the cash replacing trhese.   The Ridgeback has Gripshifts which seem to not be well thought of so again thought they would be worth replacing.

Comment: @ChrisH - We're talking mostly twist shifters and the cheap thumb shifters they put on BSOs.  Often half the shifter is broken off.  And the twist shifters often come apart inside, with the "W" spring "migrating" out of its roost.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I haven't tried this on twist shifters bit the cheap thumb ones are what I had in mind.

Comment: I've also done 'donated bike recovery" and if you're handy with tools you can probably get two usable bikes out of three donors, but you will almost certainly have to buy new tubes and tyres. Either immediately or after a little riding when they flake apart or crack and fail.

Comment: @ChrisH - The problem is that the push button shifters often have a button broken off or some such.

Comment: @Mσᶎ - Tubes aren't a problem -- we salvage plenty, and they don't deteriorate that rapidly.  Tires are the problem -- they're just too expensive to replace willy-nilly.

Comment: Maybe it's the Australian tendency to just stop riding the bike at the first puncture, be we saw a lot of donated bikes with punctured tubes. Often covered with a layer of crumbly rubber that made them annoying to fix. But if you can avoid new tubes that's great.

Answer (score 4):

Depends how they've been stored.  If they were inside a garage or otherwise dry, then that's a lot less work.  If they were outside or damp, everything will be that much closer to EOL.

Gear changes and brakes: if there's been moisture in the cables then they can suffer but housings and inner wires can be replaced.

Tyres and tubes can degrade in heat.  Oils and greases will thicken and congeal so an all-round service of bearings can be in order.

Finally, why were they unused for a long time?  Was there a fault that was too hard to fix at the time?   Look for function.

On the other side, sometimes a good wash, and a lick of paint can make an old bike appear very much nicer too.

Comment: Depending on maintenance before storage the various bearings might need maintenance or replacement too. And don’t forget to replace old brake pads.

Comment: Storage-aged (as opposed to worn down) brake pads can often be rehabilitated with some sandpaper on a flat surface, if you've got more time than money to spend.

Answer (score 3):

In my personal experience the order is roughly the following

- Chains and cassettes
- Cables
- Rear derailleur pulleys
- Chainrings

Derailleurs don't really wear out but can be accidentally broken. And as already commented, the best way of managing this is replacing parts when they wear out.

Comment: Thanks, none of the rear mechs are broken and only 1 front mech is, so I think I'll stick with the existing ones - maybe look for wear on the pulleys though.

Comment: Thanks, none of the rear mechs are broken and only 1 front mech is, so I think I'll stick with the existing ones - will look for wear on the pulleys though.  I've done all the cables with Jagwire SS/teflon jobbies, so hopefully they will be OK for a while. And I'll live with the chainrings.